# How can I refresh VS Code explorer from a extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension that get some inputs from the developer and calls some yarn/npm commands inside an custom opened terminal in order to generate a folder and some files inside it.

Everything is running ok, except that we need to manually click on the refresh button in the Explorer in order to see the resulting folder.

I would like to call a method from the extension to do that for us once the execution was completed.
I did some research on the web and found this command:

```
terminal.sendText(command);
vscode.commands.executeCommand(
                    "workbench.files.action.refreshFilesExplorer"
                  );
```

But unfortunately, it is not working as I expected.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to wait until after the command has completed before running refresh.

Does the command need to be run in the terminal? Can it be run using node's [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) instead, with you then executing `vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.files.action.refreshFilesExplorer")` after the process exits?

Comment: well, I don't think I can run "yarn / npm / ng" based commands using child_process. can I ?

Comment: Yes, you can run any commands/executables using [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)